# Merge two objects but not all properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I am struggling to merge two objects the way I need them using Node.js express and mongoDB. Below you will see both initial objects.

```json
Obj1: {
           "name":"max",
           "age":26,
           "hometown": "NY"
    }
```

```json
Obj2: {
       "id": "123",
       "favoriteteams" : ["Yankees, "Knicks"],
       "home" : "NY"
    }
```

I am currently trying:

```js
const merged = {...obj1, ...obj2.favoriteteams};
```

But that gives me

```json
merged: {
       0: "Yankees"
       1: "Knicks"
       "name":"max",
        "age":26,
        "hometown": "NY"
    }
```

But what I need is:

```json
merged: {
       "name":"max",
        "age":26,
        "hometown": "NY"
        "favoriteteams": ["Yankees", "Knicks"];
    }
```

I also have tried `const merged = {...obj1, ...obj2};`  and using Object.assign() but both obviously then mesh in the fields I don't need from obj2 (ID and home). Effectively I only need to get the favoriteteams from the second object, but I need that to be a new key in the first object and also to maintain the array response with the list of strings.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `{...obj1, favoriteteams: obj2.favoriteteams}`

Comment: @Thinker I can't believe it was that easy and I couldn't find that. It's been a long day and I'm new to node.js and mongo, thanks so much. Have a wonderful week.

Comment: How you get your obj1 and obj2? Are they some documents inside certain collection in MongoDB?

Comment: @ray obj is a json file being imported directly and obj2 is from a MongoDB collection

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `$mergeObjects` in MongoDB aggregation.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  // keep only the fields you want in obj2
  {
    "$project": {
      favoriteteams: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      obj2: "$$ROOT",
      obj1: <put your obj1 here>
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      // perform merge
      merged: {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$obj1",
          "$obj2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      // revert back to original form
      "newRoot": "$merged"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fhXJV9Uphge) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for the information Ray, I should have clarified more to your question. Obj1 is from a json file that will never touch mongo, and obj2 is from a mongodb, and the merged object needs to disappear immediately after use

Comment: @williambutcherthe99th I think it meets all your requirement. It will not update the database. You can simply get the merge result in js level.